# Problemas con sombra en un div utilizando transition

Tags: css3

Tengo un problema con la visualización con una sombra sobre un div.
Detalle el codigo en un codepen

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dsebao/pen/RybYPx?editors=1100)

Que estoy haciendo mal?

**Edit:** En chrome lo visualizo asi
Al parecer es un bug de renderización.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
article.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
article.item article.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
article.item article.item:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
article.item article.item::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(46, 34, 34, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -90px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -90px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
article.item article.item.color::after {
  background: rgba(115, 48, 200, 0.6);
}
article.item article.item .over {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
article.item article.item .over .content {
  padding: 20px;
}
article.item article.item .over .content p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
article.item article.item .over .date {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffef1f;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
article.item article.item .over h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
article.item article.item .over h2 a {
  color: #fff;
}
article.item article.item .over h2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
article.item article.item a.img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
article.item article.item a.img img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
article.item:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
article.item::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(46, 34, 34, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -90px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -90px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
article.item.color::after {
  background: rgba(115, 48, 200, 0.6);
}
article.item .over {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
article.item .over .content {
  padding: 20px;
}
article.item .over .content p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
article.item .over .date {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffef1f;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
article.item .over h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
article.item .over h2 a {
  color: #fff;
}
article.item .over h2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
article.item a.img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
article.item a.img img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<article class="item">
 <a href="http://elemultiespacio.com.ar/hollywood-nigth/" class="img"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400x400" alt="Hollywood Nigth"></a>
    <div class="over">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="date">domingo </div>
            <h2 class="downlines"><a href="http://elemultiespacio.com.ar/hollywood-nigth/">Test</a></h2>                                    <p>My content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: los enlaces a paginas externas tiene el riesgo de desaparecer en el futuro. Aquí tambien hay un fiddle en donde puedes agregar tu código, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/156719/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Deberías traer el código aquí como dice @ReneLimon y dar más información ¿Qué problema tienes exactamente con la sombra?¿Qué quieres conseguir?

Comment: Ahi actualice la pregunta con el fiddle y una screenshot. Gracias @ReneLimon. Lo que quiero hacer es que no se vean los cuadrados de la imagen y se vea una sombra (que es la que esta generando el problema)

Comment: quieres que se vea una sombra interna?

tu código no muestra esas sombras cuadradas así que no se bien a que te refieres

Comment: podrías ilustrar mas o menos como quieres que se vea?